# How do I use Excel to produce a table showing what plant species are likely to be present based on location and habitat?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm a botanist and I am trying to produce an Excel table that filters a very long list of species based on location and basic habitat.

I have created a master table with 200 rows for each species and along the columns are firstly locations (for instance column b for England, column b for Scotland and so on) and then after location the columns are basic habitats (i.e. column f for woodland, column g for grassland, column h for aquatic). All cells contain a YES or NO relevant to each species showing what geographic location and what habitat the species occurs in.

I want to produce a table that asks me where my site is and what habitats it supports and uses this to narrow down what species are likely to be present. For instance, if I had a site in London that supported woodland, grassland and a hedgerow I could use the filters to bring the species list down from 200+ to hopefully a handful of species!

Any ideas on how to produce this would be great. I've attached a picture of my current worksheet.

[image]

Comment: Hopefully someone with good Excel-fu can answer but I wanted to point out that this would be a nice use-case for an R Shiny app, or even just the R DataTable (`DT`) library on its own in an HTML compiled R Markdown. [Example description](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html), [example demo app](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/012-datatables/)

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straight forward

You have laid out your information in essentially two side by side tables with their rows lined up.  Table 1 is your location, and Table 2 is your habitat.  Basically you want to generate a list or row numbers where there is a yes in the matching location column and a yes in the matching habitat column.  Based on that list of row numbers, pull the corresponding Species.

In order to do that lets make some assuptions:

- The sheet were all your data is located is called SData
- The data is laid out from A1:R200
- Row 1 is a header row
- Columns C:I are location columns
- Columns J:R are habitat locations
- The location you are looking for is B1
- The habitat you are looking for is D1
- You list will be displayed in A2:B200

1) Determine Location Column

```
=INDEX(SData!C2:I200,0,MATCH($B$1,SData!$C$1:$I$1,0)
```

2)  Determine Habitat Column

```
=INDEX(SData!J2:R200,0,MATCH($D$1,SData!$J$1:$R$1,0)
```

3)  Determine which rows contain Yes

Both Habitat and Location need to contain yes to be an acceptable row.  If cell = yes will be True.  In math operations Excel treats True as 1 and False as 0. So if both cells in a row are yes, you will have 1*1=1.  If both are FALSE then you will have 0*0=0.  And if one cell is Yes and the other is No then the result will be 1*0=1.

So in order to do this, the aggregate function will be use.  It will perform array like operations for certain functions like 14 and 15 which will be used.  Aggregate can also be instructed to ignore errors.  So we will set AGGREGATE up to divide the Row number by the condition check for yes.  As a result you will either wind up with the row number, or a divide by 0 error which aggregate will turn around and ignore those results.

```
=INDEX(SData!A:A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(SData!$A$2:$A$200)/((INDEX(SData!$C$2:$I$200,0,MATCH($B$1,SData!$C$1:$I$1,0))="yes")*(INDEX(SData!$J$2:$R$200,0,MATCH($B$1,SData!$J$1:$R$1,0))="yes")),ROW(A1)))
```

Place that above formula in A2 and copy down and across to B200.  The problem that I foresee so far is when you run out of rows that match your data.  In this situation or if you had all no results, an error would be created.  In order to avoid error results in your cells, you can wrap the whole formula above in an IFERROR formula so that "" is displayed when an error is the result.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SData!A:A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(SData!$A$2:$A$200)/((INDEX(SData!$C$2:$I$200,0,MATCH($B$1,SData!$C$1:$I$1,0))="yes")*(INDEX(SData!$J$2:$R$200,0,MATCH($D$1,SData!$J$1:$R$1,0))="yes")),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Example:

Data Table:

[image]

Result Sheet 1:

[image]

Result Sheet 2:

[image]